# Python client establish connection with socket.io v1.0 and fire event by websocket

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am using socket.io version 1.0 on the server.(There might be migration problem for versions below 1.0) I have established the connection to the socket.io server with websocket library in python. However, after establishing conneciton i cannot fire events on server side. In docs, it is indicated that the client message, must be sth like this;

`data = '42{"name":"fileUploadEvent", "args":[{"msg":"test"}]}'`

I think it must fire fileUploadEvent and pass msg paramter to it. But it does'nt fire anything.

When I check the logs, there is no event firing log at the server. Is there any error on protocol or my json format.

Thank you for replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format is

```
data = '42["fileUploadEvent",{"msg":"test"}]'
```